# Is this stream possible ? stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.name!).snapshots()

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to see if the document Id that I got can be placed in the name of the collection. this  is what I got so far. I don't know if this is possible but it doesn't give me any errors I think that my logic is wrong?

```
String? name;
  
          StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.name!).snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot)



class HomeTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference _servicesRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("categories");

          FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _servicesRef.get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot)
           
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => CategoPage(name: document.id, )
                        ));
```

I there was no error but it kept returning to this

```
cirularProgressIndicator()
```

[this is my collection at firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTpXO.png)

Comment: there's a lot wrong with your code example, besides the syntax errors, the missing brackets and all that stuff. you're not showing the `cirularProgressIndicator` you say is being shown. at the top you have half a `StreamBuilder`. can you show us the actual code that is giving you issues